# How to call spring controller method through ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

Here is my Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping( value={"/home"},params="userAction=loadHomePage",method=Request.POST)
public String viewPage(@ModelAttribute("dataForm") formData, Model model,HttpServletRequest req)throws Exception{
...
}
```

How to pass the params value through ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.. Let me know if further guidance is needed..

```
var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange= function(){
             if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {

             }
        };
        request.open("POST", "/home", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send("userAction=loadHomePage");
    };
```

To set the model object:

```
    var formData= new FormData();
    formData.append('username' , 'payal');
    formData.append('id' , 123456);
    request.send(formData);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I need to reload the page also, to make changes in all html element according to back end data.